# How to create a mult-line timeline graph of tweets posted

Tags: r, ggplot2, sentiment-analysis, ggplotly

I have a dataset of 56,040 tweets in R called 'tweets' collected in the week following the roe v wade announcement. I'm attempting to analyze using sentiment analysis scores. I have three columns:

1. 'stance' = included for each tweet - includes either 'life' or 'choice' depending on which stance the tweet is taking.
2. 'POSIX' = the timestamp of when the date was posted, currently in YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS format.
3. 'score' = the sentiment score for each tweet, ranging from around -10 to 10.

I've tried various ways without success and honestly don't know what I'm doing but figure this can't be *that* difficult. I'm attempting to create a line graph with two lines (one for life and another for choice) over the course of the timeframe (right after midnight on the 22nd until 11:59 on the 3rd) showing the average sentiment score of tweets by hour, controlling for the number of tweets that were sent out at that hour. Any suggestions?

So far I've attempted various ggplot and plotly attempts with no success. Pls help lol

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and post your data and any code you've written so far into your question.

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.